# how to send data http://localhost/someproject/editid/1 instead of http://localhost/someproject/editid=1

Tags: php, json, web-services

how to send data `http://localhost/someproject/editid/1` instead of  `http://localhost/someproject/client_list.php?editid=1`

please let me know how the above url works,we need to use any api or webservices to pass above url parameters in php

Comment: Do you mean http://localhost/someproject/editid?id=1 where $_GET['id'] you have to use?

Comment: Hi Sanjay , thaq for your quick replay its like  http://localhost/someproject/clients_list.php?id=1

Comment: i want to pass in the url like  http://localhost/someproject/clients_list/id/1   and to pass like above do we need to write any api

Comment: submit your form code

Comment: posted my  form code Drop Shadow

Answer (score 1):

use your form like

```
<a href="client_register.php/editid/<?php echo $row['id'];?>
```

and in your php code get the id through

```
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
 $segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
```

$segments will be an array , and u will get your id in this array like

```
Array
(
  [0] => 
  [1] => test.php
  [2] => id
  [3] => 9
)
```

Comment: thaq for your replay @Drop Shadow do you know to to create api in php  and can you send me some reference links , it will be very helpful to me and thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

                                           // code by satish nakenaboina to retrive the data ie client list from db and to display
                                                include_once('db_config.php');
                                                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tblusers`") or die(mysql_error());

                                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                                           ?>
                                            <td class="a-center">
                                                <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class=" sorting_1"><?php echo $row['USER_FIRST_NAME']; ?></td>
                                            <td class=""><?php echo $row['SPECIALITY']; ?></td>
                                            <td class=""><?php echo $row['REGISTERED_PHONE_NUMBER']; ?></td>
                                            <td class=""><?php echo $row['REGISTERED_EMAIL']; ?> </td>
                                            <td class=""><i data="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="status_checks btn <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'?>"><?php echo ($row['status'])? 'Active' : 'Inactive'?></i></td>
                                            <td class="a-right a-right"><a href="client_register.php?editid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Edit</a> <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Delete</a></td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <?php 
                                                }
                                        ?>
```